# try-catch in Visualforce extension

Tags: visualforce, try-catch

I have a VF page which must display markups conditionnaly. So I use an outputText tag with a "render" condition.
At first, the render condition tested a variable directly:

```
<apex:outputText rendered="{!theObject.Surface__c > 0 }">
```

It appears that for some instance records of *theObject*, the field *Surface__c* is not populated, which leads to a message "The value 'null' is not valid for operator '>'".

So I try to test if the field has been extracted by my SOQL query.

My idea is to use a Boolean *get;set;* value, and use *try-catch* structure to test the field presence and set the boolean value to test in the VF code:

```
<apex:outputText rendered="{!isSurfacePopulated}">
```

I tried different coding and did not succeed to trap the exception. I finally ended up with the following Apex code:

```
public Boolean isSurfacePopulated { get; set; }
public MyControllerExtension(ApexPages.StandardController stdController) {
    ID objID = stdController.getId();
    MyObject theObject = [SELECT Surface__c FROM MyObject WHERE ID = :objID];
    try {
        isSurfacePopulated = theObject.Surface__c > 0;
        system.debug('No Exception triggered');
    }
    catch( Exception e ) {
        system.debug('Exception trapped');
        isSurfacePopulated = false;
    }
}
```

Not only I don't trap the exception, but the code doesn't even seem to execute the try block (the debug log doesn't show any of the system.debug() text I specified).

I don't undertstand how that is possible. Do I miss something ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The merge expression engine that Salesforce uses for Visualforce pages operates on slightly different rules than Apex does.

I believe that the way operators work in Apex was changed sometime in the past 2 years or so (around the time the Safe Navigation Operator, `?.`, was introduced?) to make the comparison operators return `false` if one argument is null and the other argument is an "Integer, Double, Date, or Datetime". This is part of the scenario that you're experiencing.

So given that, the try/catch isn't necessary in your controller extension.

As for why you're not hitting either debug, the only explanation I can think of is that `stdController.getId()` is returning null or an Id for a different SObject type. That'd cause your extension's query to return no rows (and run into a `No rows for assignment to SObject` exception, which is outside of your try/catch).

Double check your logs to see the precise error that you're getting (if any), and double check to see what Id you're sending/receiving (you need to be including `id=<record Id here>` in the query string for `getId()` to be able to pick it up).

Comment: Thank you Derek.

Comment: Thank you Derek. Let me tell you what I did next.
I first rseolved by setting a value in the field Surface__c in every record. Then I could notice that the texte "No exception triggered" appeared in the Debug Log. Then I selected a record and removed value in its Surface__c field : I still can see the "No exception triggered"  in the Debug Log, but no error is shown in the VF Page. This behavior still remains a mistery.
Besides of that, the Safe Navigation operator works perfectly well.